# "Лето-2016" или "Лето 2016"?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

Как правильно оформить предложение:
а) Лето-2016
б) Лето 2016

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: *лето-2016*. Неизменяемое приложение, передаваемое на письме цифрами, присоединяется к слову с помощью дефиса. Однако если приложение присоединяется к нескольким словам (например: *утренние разминки — 2005*), дефис заменяется на тире.

Comment: Обратите внимание: на письме дефис не отделяется от слов пробелами, например *дру**г-з**атейник*. А вот тире отделяется: *Он**и — п**рекрасные люди*.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54119/discussion-on-answer-by-aer----).

Answer (score 0):

Лето - 2016: лето - две тысячи шестнадцать.

Лето 2016: лето две тысячи шестнадцатого.

Я бы прочитала так.

Comment: Так какой же вариант правильный?

Comment: Первый или второй?

Comment: Думаю, оба правильные, смотря что Вами задумано и как Вы читаете.